# Cannot install IBM worklight

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: IBM Worklight Studio 1.0.0.v20120606_0304 (com.ibm.imp.tools.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.v20120606_0304)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (epp.package.jee 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Java Development Tools UI 3.6.1.r361_v20100825-0800 (org.eclipse.jdt.ui 3.6.1.r361_v20100825-0800)
    Java Development Tools UI 3.5.2.r352_v20100106-0800 (org.eclipse.jdt.ui 3.5.2.r352_v20100106-0800)
    Java Development Tools UI 3.6.2.r362_v20110203 (org.eclipse.jdt.ui 3.6.2.r362_v20110203)
    Java Development Tools UI 3.5.1.r351_v20090821-0800 (org.eclipse.jdt.ui 3.5.1.r351_v20090821-0800)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: IBM Web Editor Common 1.0.0.v20120517_1932 (com.ibm.etools.webtools.webedit.common 1.0.0.v20120517_1932)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui [3.6.2,4.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: IBM Worklight Studio 1.0.0.v20120606_0304 (com.ibm.imp.tools.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.v20120606_0304)
    To: com.ibm.imp.webtools.core.feature.feature.group 1.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Web Tools Core 1.0.0.v20120517_1932 (com.ibm.imp.webtools.core.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.v20120517_1932)
    To: com.ibm.etools.webtools.webedit.common [1.0.0.v20120517_1932]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (epp.package.jee 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.3.1.20100916-1202]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
    To: org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.5.1.r351_v20090810-0600-7r88FEoFI0WTo6Az-1qFRHm37ChJ (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.5.1.r351_v20090810-0600-7r88FEoFI0WTo6Az-1qFRHm37ChJ)
    To: org.eclipse.jdt.ui [3.5.1.r351_v20090821-0800]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.5.2.r352_v20100108-7r88FEwFI0WTuoBl0iaG0tyhfZH6 (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.5.2.r352_v20100108-7r88FEwFI0WTuoBl0iaG0tyhfZH6)
    To: org.eclipse.jdt.ui [3.5.2.r352_v20100106-0800]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.6.1.r361_v20100714-0800-7z8XFUSFLFlmgLc5z-Bvrt8-HVkH (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.6.1.r361_v20100714-0800-7z8XFUSFLFlmgLc5z-Bvrt8-HVkH)
    To: org.eclipse.jdt.ui [3.6.1.r361_v20100825-0800]
```

I am getting this error, when i try to install the worklight plugin for eclipse. how to solve this dependency

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to install Eclipse Indigo package (either Java or Java EE) and then install worklight.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Worklight Studio requires JDT 3.6 or higher. However you are using Eclipse 3.5 Java EE package, JDT can't be updated to 3.6 due to some other requirements.

You can try to update your Eclipse Java EE package to latest firstly, or directly install IBM Worklight Studio into a fresh Eclipse 3.6+.